# Button to Present ViewController After Tutorial (which Loads For 1st Time Only)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a tutorial `ViewController` called `tutorialViewController` which only presents itself for the first time the app is launched.  This is how I do that:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL hasRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstRun"];

    if (!hasRunBefore) {
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstRun"];
        self.window.rootViewController = [tutorialViewController new];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// RESideMenu Stuff that Must Be Done

        leftSideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[leftSideMenuViewController alloc] init];
        rightSideMenuViewController *rightMenuViewController = [[rightSideMenuViewController alloc] init];

        musicPlayerViewController *navigationController = [[homeViewController alloc] init];


        RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
                                                                        leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                                       rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
        sideMenuViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = 1;

        sideMenuViewController.delegate = self;
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOpacity = 0.6;
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowRadius = 12;
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowEnabled = YES;

        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    }

    else
    {
        NSLog (@"Not the first time this controller has been loaded");

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[homeViewController alloc] init]];

// RESideMenu Stuff that Must Be Done

        leftSideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[leftSideMenuViewController alloc] init];
        rightSideMenuViewController *rightMenuViewController = [[rightSideMenuViewController alloc] init];

        RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
                                                                        leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                                       rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
        sideMenuViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = 1;

        sideMenuViewController.delegate = self;
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOpacity = 0.6;
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowRadius = 12;
        sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowEnabled = YES;
        self.window.rootViewController = sideMenuViewController;

        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    }
```

This works well so far - if I load the app for the first time, it shows tutorialViewController.  If I close it and open it again, it shows homeViewController.

I'd just like to know how to add an IBAction to take me from tutorialViewController to homeViewController.  Currently, I wrote this:

```
- (IBAction)goToHomeViewController:(id)sender {

    homeViewController *navigationController = [homeViewController new];

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
    }];

    NSLog(@"Start button pressed");
}
```

It presents `homeViewController` but it does not show the navigation bar, etc. - as it would if `homeViewController` was the `rootViewController`.

Here are some more details

- `tutorialViewController` does not show a status bar or a navigation bar.  It is simply a scrollview that takes up the whole screen.

  - 'homeViewController`has a navigation bar with a left bar button and right bar button that brings up other`viewControllers`.

I've searched other SO questions but they are mostly to do with Storyboards, **which I am not using**.  Just .xibs (and .h and .m).

***How do I present `homeViewController` from `tutorialViewController` just as it would display if `homeViewController` was the `rootViewController`?***

Answer (score 0):

Wrap homeViewController in a UINavigationController should work.

```
[self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController] animated:YES: completion:nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

In your '*if*' condition add *tutorialViewController* as

`UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[tutorialViewController alloc] init]];`

And in the *goToHomeViewController* function add,

```
 homeViewController *navigationController = [homeViewController new];
[self.navigation pushViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
```

So first time the *tutorialViewController* act as rootview controller and if you want to hide *NavigationBar* add following code,

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```